# Should self-answered questions be protected or marked as a FAQ?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, asking-questions, self-answer

I have noticed that a particular member has asked a question, and, straight after just answered and accepted his answer. I presume that this is acceptable, as it has not been closed. Should the question therefore be protected, or, at least marked as some kind of FAQ?

Comment: _"Should the question therefore be protected, or, at least marked as some kind of FAQ?"_ Why? It's no different from any other question/answer pairs.

Comment: Related: [What is this “answer your own question” jazz?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/132886/what-is-this-answer-your-own-question-jazz) as well as the [linked blog post](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/)

Comment: @downvoters - Why so many? :S Nothing wrong with the question IMO

Comment: It's an okay meta question. However, afterwards you made a suggestion, which people disagree with, hence the downvote parade.

Comment: @Compass I didn't make a suggestion, I asked a question. Hence the "?" I did not suggest it, I asked whether or not it should be marked as a FAQ..

Answer (score 18):

> I presume that this is acceptable

Yes, it is. We even have a checkbox that open up an answer form on the "Ask Question" page (look for "Answer your own question" at the bottom of that page).

[image: Answer your own question]

> Should the question therefore be protected, or, at least marked as some kind of FAQ?

No. why should it? That a member of the community decided to post a self-answer doesn't automatically make it a good set of question/answer, doesn't mean they are of high quality, are an FAQ or that it should be protected - perhaps someone else has a better answer.

Comment: Heh, two in a row.

Comment: I can quit at any time.